# Streaming a file off a server

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to stream the recorded audio from my raspberry pis to my desktop computer which handles pocketsphinx phenomenally. I can pipe the audio using

`arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE  | ssh -C user@192.168.86.101 sox - test.wav`

And then run it using 
`pocketsphinx_continuous -dict ~/4568.dic -lm ~/4568.lm -infile ~/test.wav`

But once it reaches the end of the file, it stops, even though the file is still writing. Is there a way to keep it open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else finding this,

`arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE | ssh -C user@192.168.86.101 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /dev/stdin`

is how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Use [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) instead of a regular file. Also you can file an issue at [github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/) requesting that `pocketsphinx_continious` should be able to read from `stdin`. And of course you're welcome to submit such a patch.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, but that looks like a very promising solution.

Comment: I am not sure that works, or I am using it wrong. I tried, mkfifo /tmp/pipe then arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE  /tmp/pipe and finally in another term ssh -C mingram@192.168.86.101 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /tmp/pipe but it can't find the pipe.

Comment: Also, arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE | ssh -C mingram@192.168.86.101 sox - /tmp/pipe throws sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of `/tmp/pipe'

Comment: The second variant is the right one, but as you didn't provide the suffix sox couldn't decide about the format. Either give the pipe a suffix, e.g. `/tmp/pipe.wav` or specify the desired format as the sox argument.

Comment: yeah, I got it all running. It still just ends at the end of the file, though. arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 | ssh -C mingram@192.168.86.101 sox - /tmp/pipe.wav then ssh -C mingram@192.168.86.101 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /tmp/pipe.wav

Comment: Can you elaborate on "ends at the end of the file"? I'm now not sure about what you expect to get eventually.

Comment: The anwser was arecord -D plughw:1,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE | ssh -C user@192.168.86.101 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /dev/stdin and end of file meaning that it races to meet where it is recording and ends.